# Add payload to axios request

Tags: javascript, rest, request, axios

I have some questions to my axios request. 
To get the information from the API I need a key and a secret in my request - is this in my example correct implemented and where can I find the correct key/ secret?

And how can I add a payload to my axios request to get a specific answer to the request?

```
var my_url = "https://secret.de";

var myResponse = "";

function My(axios) {
  this.axios = axios;
  this.vue = this.getMyResponse();
  this.vue.getData();
}

My.prototype.getMyResponse = function() {
  var myRequest = new Vue({
    headers: {
      "consumerKey": "key",
      "consumerSecret": "secret",
    },
    el: '#widget1',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      myResponseData: ''
    },
    methods: {
      getData: function () {
        axios.all([
          axios.post(my_url, {
            username: "username",
            password: "password"
          })
        ])
        .then(axios.spread(function (myResponseOne) {
          myWidget(myResponseOne);
          myRequest.$data.myResponseData = myResponse;
        }))
      }
    },
  });

  timeout = setInterval(myRequest.getData, 60000);
  return myRequest;
};
```

Thank you!